# Have a rotating image covering body only on front page?

Tags: images

On the front side I wish to have, between the header and footer, 5-6 images that are rotating every x seconds. It would be great if it could span 100% of the width but it is also okay if it is just centered. This is only on the first page though, the rest of the site I wish to have as I have (a grey border and white background). Does anyone know a plugin that make this work for me? Preferablly without any type of clicks. Also preferably with arrows that suggests that you can click back and forth between the images.

Comment: Usually to change the look and feel of a page you need to create a child theme or change themes, not add a plugin. It's the theme that controls the functionality and appearance of particular pages.

Comment: Okay, any tip on how I can do that? I created a child theme already and I am trying a few things but I have yet to make it work the way I want. The rotating image supersized-plugin seems correct but I cannot get it working correctly.

Comment: It depends on the parent theme, but one of the most common files used for the homepage is `front-page.php`. See if your parent theme has that and if so, copy it into your child theme, then delete everything between `get_header()` and `get_footer()`, then work on adding the images. How do you want to store these homepage images? Are you adding a theme options page so the user can change them? Will they always be hard-coded into the theme?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help WebElaine.
 What I did instead was install a nextgen gallery and that was great. I tried WP supersized but did not manage to get it working. So nextgen gallery solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, seriously? You've installed NextGen just to put few images on one site? Are you sure you're OK with all the effects of that plugin? (Additional DB tables, a lot of queries, and so on?)

Comment: To be honest, I am not good enough to understand exactly what that means but the websites work fine now. I am just happy with the result.